# What is the meaning of this Web kit JavaScript warning? (Thickbox)?

Tags: jquery, webkit

Webkit Develoepr tools says the following Javascript Error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///D:/wamp/www/projects/c1-marching-band2/instruments.html from frame with URL file:///D:/wamp/www/projects/c1-marching-band2/iframeModal.html?placeValuesBefore. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
file:///D:/wamp/www/projects/c1-marching-band2/iframeModal.html?placeValuesBefore:15Uncaught TypeError: Property 'tb_remove' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

I'm trying to close the Thickbox div (iframe) pressing a submit button. But I think there's something wrong with `'tb_remove'`. (Just in Chrome)

It doe work in their official page: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be running on a server. The point of origin must match.

If you try and run this on localhost, or upload it to a web server my guess is it will start working.

> Domains, protocols and ports must
> match.
>
> file:///D:/wamp/www/projects...

suggests you are running the files direct from your drive rather than through apache or alike.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not doing anything that goes against the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)